# Rentalcars full coverage insurance

Tags: car-rentals, insurance

I rented a car abroad  at www.rentalcars.com and also purchased  the full coverage  insurance.
When i returned the car i bumped into a pole and damaged the car that happened at the last day of the rental . 
The rental company (one of the biggest  ) charged for the damage about 650 dollars.
Will the insurance  pay the excess  that i paid directly to the  car rental company ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Rental Cars Full Protection page](https://www.rentalcars.com/FullProtection.do):

> Our Full Protection waiver product covers damage to all exterior and
>   mechanical parts of the car and has no excess: whatever the car hire
>   company withholds from your deposit for damage, we cover.

That seems pretty clear: they should pay.

However, the wording of the policy document you should have received will be the definitive reference. You should check that carefully.

Comment: Make sure you pay attention to details and respond quickly with required info and documents. They should pay, but don't want to, so don't provide excuses.